# Azure Pipeline - C# Build project depending on another project in another repository

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have the following situation:
On **AzureDevops**:

**Project A -
Repository A**

```
Module3/Module3.csproj
Module1/Module1.csproj
Module2/Module2.csproj
Module1/Module1.csproj
- Solution.sln
```

**Project B -
Repository B**

```
ModuleCore/ModuleCore.csproj
-ModuleCore.sln
```

**ModuleCore** is added to several projects.

In *VisualStudio*, when we are going to compile **project A** , I add ModuleCore.csproj as an existing project, and the compilation works.

I've done several pipelines on azure devops, with no dependency between projects, but with this one I'm having difficulty.

When I try to do the Build, it doesn't find the ModuleCore and breaks.

My current build task is:

```
 - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '$(solution)'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

How do I build **Project A** and link **Project B** as a dependency?
Is there any other way to perform this Build in the pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

As Modulecore is being used in several projects, assuming it's a library it's best adding it to nuget (organisation level) repository and restore it while building the main solution.

Comment: Thanks S Rao, i will try via Nuget.